# Count Pairs from two arrays with even sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

**Problem Statement**

Given two arrays A[] and B[] of N and M integers respectively. The task is to count the number of unordered pairs formed by choosing an element from array A[] and other from array B[] in such a way that their sum is an even number.
Note that an element will only be a part of a single pair.

Input: A[] = {9, 14, 6, 2, 11}, B[] = {8, 4, 7, 20}
Output: 4
{9, 7}, {14, 8}, {6, 4} and {2, 20} are the valid pairs.

**Source**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-from-two-arrays-with-even-sum/

**My Problem**
I am wondering how output doesn't have so many other pairs whose sum will be even i.e. {11,7}, {2,3} etc. and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the question, **Element will only be a part of single pair**

{11,7} and {2,3} are already considered in {9, 7} and {2, 20}.

Answer (score 0):

It's given in the problem statement, 
***Note that an element will only be a part of a single pair.***
That means 7 has already been paired in {9, 7} so you can't pair {11, 7}